# How to remove serial number which are overlapping over the cell contents of DataGridView Sequentially?

Tags: c#

[image]
I want to remove the numbers overlapping on the cell of DataGridview.What should I do??

private void SearchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable cmbTable = new DataTable();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dataGridViewTextBoxColumn = default(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn);
            int index = 0;
            int totalWidth = 0;

```
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        cmbTable.Columns.Add("RecCode");
        cmbTable.Columns.Add("TheName");

        // set the datagrid columns and width etc
        for (index = 0; index <= this.displayColumns.Length - 1; index++)
        {
            dataGridViewTextBoxColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = this.displayColumns[index];
            dataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = this.displayHeaders[index];
            dataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = this.displayWidths[index];
            this.DgSearch.Columns.Add(dataGridViewTextBoxColumn);

            totalWidth += this.displayWidths[index];

            if (this.DgSearch.DataSource is DataTable)
            {
                this.DgSearch.DataSource = ((DataTable)DgSearch.DataSource).DefaultView;
            }

            if (index == 0)
            {
                this.Text = "Search: ";
            }

            cmbTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { this.displayColumns[index], this.displayHeaders[index] });
        }

        this.columnValue = string.Empty;
        this.Width = totalWidth + 25;

        // Column Headers in combo box to select the search column name
        this.CmbColumnName.DisplayMember = "TheName";
        this.CmbColumnName.ValueMember = "RecCode";
        this.CmbColumnName.DataSource = cmbTable;
        this.CmbColumnName.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }




protected override void OnRowPostPaint(DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        { //this method overrides the DataGridView's RowPostPaint event 
            //in order to automatically draw numbers on the row header cells
            //and to automatically adjust the width of the column containing
            //the row header cells so that it can accommodate the new row
            //numbers,

            //store a string representation of the row number in 'strRowNumber'
            string strRowNumber = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();

            //prepend leading zeros to the string if necessary to improve
            //appearance. For example, if there are ten rows in the grid,
            //row seven will be numbered as "07" instead of "7". Similarly, if 
            //there are 100 rows in the grid, row seven will be numbered as "007".
            while (strRowNumber.Length < this.RowCount.ToString().Length) strRowNumber = "0" + strRowNumber;

            //determine the display size of the row number string using
            //the DataGridView's current font.
            SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strRowNumber, this.Font);

            //adjust the width of the column that contains the row header cells 
            //if necessary
            if (this.RowHeadersWidth < (int)(size.Width + 20)) this.RowHeadersWidth = (int)(size.Width + 20);

            //this brush will be used to draw the row number string on the
            //row header cell using the system's current ControlText color
            Brush b = SystemBrushes.ControlText;

            //draw the row number string on the current row header cell using
            //the brush defined above and the DataGridView's default font
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strRowNumber, this.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 15, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + ((e.RowBounds.Height - size.Height) / 2));

            //call the base object's OnRowPostPaint method
            base.OnRowPostPaint(e);
        } //end OnRowPostPaint method
```

Comment: Could you provide some code ? Maybe the code you use to fill the datagrid ?

Comment: Leon I have added the code in my question

Comment: Well, you haven't found the code that does this yet.  Smells like an inappropriate CellPainting event handler.  Comment out code if you have no idea how this happened.

Comment: Sir I have added the Paint Event. Can you just check whats happening??

Comment: You don't have any row headers, so painting them isn't going to turn out well.  Set the RowHeadersVisible property to True.